# smartsheet odbc driver Cyrillic symbols

Tags: php, odbc, smartsheet-api-2.0

I'm trying to use the ability to access Smartsheet data via the ODBC driver. http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/odbc-docs/ in php.

All is well, only the symbols on the Cyrillic are displayed by the question marks (????)

```
$conn = odbc_connect("Smartsheet","programmer*********","*****484");
if (!$conn)
    return;
$query = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT * FROM Заказы__4654483440461700s_");
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($query)) {
    $list[] = array_decode($row);
}
```

[image: debug query]

Comment: The Smartsheet ODBC driver should return UTF-8 data. In order to separate ODBC issues from PHP issues, can you try to pull the data into some app like Excel and see what the results are?

Comment: In excel, everything is fine. In the ODBC logs, the Smartsheet driver writes to UTF-8. But in php the sequence of bytes (in HEX format) is always transmitted: EFBFBD

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GnlBpzCKCyLe8dPxziaYg7L_liPUyKv-/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GnlBpzCKCyLe8dPxziaYg7L_liPUyKv-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: That's just the Unicode replacement character ('?') as UTF-8. I'm not very familiar with PHP but I suspect that means PHP thinks it can't represent the text in the client character set. You may have to set the client character set to UTF-8 `Client_CSet=UTF-8`.in the ODBC connection string. This may help: https://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb01072.html